# ASP.Net MVC5 Password requierd validation prevents me from submittung

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-5, passwords

I have model named 'Customer' that has a property named 'Password'. In the Create page of Customer When I submit the form, the password field clears and password validation message appears again and prevents me from submitting.

Comment: have you displayed the "Password" text on UI?

Comment: 0
down vote
accept

I've found the solution, I'd added the password to the model but didn't recreate 'CustomerController' and only recreated the views of Customer. so the controller didn't even pass the password. It solved with deleting and recreating a scaffolded controller and view for 'Customer' Model.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, I'd added the password to the model but didn't recreate 'CustomerController' and only recreated the views of Customer. so the controller didn't even pass the password. It solved with deleting and recreating a scaffolded controller and view for 'Customer' Model.